# KendoUI Grid: custom edit form with datepicker returning false format

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm getting stuck using a KendoUI grid. So far, the setup works as hoped. I created a custom datasource with 5 entries, all containing a title, description and value. The values can be different, they can either be: boolean, numeric, text, date or time.

using a custom KendoTemplate for the edit popup, I can get the popup to show the correct field type according to what the value is:

```
<!-- Datefield -->
#if($.isNumeric(value) == false && value.match(/^\d{2}([.\/-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/)) {#
<li>
    <label>Waarde</label>
    <input id="datepicker" data-bind="value:value" style="width: 40%;" />
</li> 
#} else if($.isNumeric(value) == false && value.match('([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]')) {#
<li>
    <label>Waarde</label>
    <input id="timepicker" data-bind="value:value" style="width: 40%;" />
</li> 
<!-- Yes/No Radio button if value is J(=Yes) or N(=No) -->    
#} else if (value == "J" || value == "N") {#
<li>
    <label>Waarde</label>
    <input type="radio" name="value" data-bind="checked:value" value="J" /> Ja
    <input type="radio" name="value" data-bind="checked:value" value="N" /> Nee
</li>                   
<!-- If the value is Numeric then show a numeric textbox -->
#} else if($.isNumeric(value)) {#                                           
<li>
    <label>Waarde</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:value" data-role="numerictextbox" style="width:50%;" />
</li>                   
<!-- Else: textfield for the value -->
#}else {#                                           
<li>
    <label>Waarde</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:value" class="k-textbox" />
</li>  
#}#
```

So far so good, this works like it is supposed to. The datepicker & timepicker are created as soon as a popup is opened in the 'edit' method belonging to KendoGrid as follows:

```
if($('#datepicker').length > 0) {
    console.log('datefield');
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
        format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
        parseFormats: ["dd-MM-yyyy"]    
    }); 
}
if($('#timepicker').length > 0) {
    console.log('timefield');
    $("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
        timeFormat: "HH:mm" 
    }); 
}
```

However(!) one thing is going wrong. No mather what I tried, the returning value that is being posted by the edit form is not containing a date such as `19-11-2013` but contains a date like `19-11-2013T00:00:00.000Z`. At least the basics of the script are working, but due to this format this field is recognized as 'time' instead of 'date' after editting: I really need just the dd-mm-yyyy notification and HH:ii for time.

I've search the KendoForums, Google & StackOverflow but I can't seem to find anyone having the same problem. It might be because I'm using the wrong search keywords.. whatever may be the case: is there anyone that has experienced the same issue or who knows what the solution is?

//Edit: a little addition to make the question more clear (I hope):

1. Creating the KendoGrid works
2. Binding a custom template form to the edit popup works aswel
3. At first all fields display the correct type (bool/numeric/date/time/text)
4. INSIDE the edit popup the date format is correct as I need id
5. The error occures when saving the data, the value returned by the popup back to the datasource contains a YYYY-mm-ddTHH:ii:ss.000Z format instead of dd-mm-YYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo UI stores dates as a JavaScript `Date` object so it is always stored as it (no matter how it is displayed or entered).

Either accept this format on the server or convert it to `dd-mm-YYYY` in the `create` and `update` functions of the `DataSource.transport`.

You can do it implementing a function in [`transport.create.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.create.data) and [`transport.update.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.create.data) or [`transport.parameterMap`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap).

Comment: Yep, I noticed the date objects. Only thing that is kind of in the way of this approach is that I can not figure out wether it's a date or a time field that needs to be updated. Any ideas?

Comment: But you know what you are willing to store, don't you? Is the type of data the only way of knowing if it is date or time? why do not use two different fields?

Comment: For now it's the only way yes. The reason is that the input is coming from another system, a 2nd field is not an option (at least.. as a last option perhaps)..

Comment: I stored a value-type string along with the data. No other option. Thanks for your help. The problem of formatting in the grid was easy: I totally forgot I could alter the format using the PHP DataSource!